# Nbconvert 5.6.1 doesn't want to install

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub, nbconvert

I am trying to install nbconvert 5.6.1 with this command:

sudo -E pip install --upgrade nbconvert==5.6.1

and it said that it is successfully installed.

But after running command jupyter --version I get this:

Selected Jupyter core packages...

IPython          : 7.30.1

ipykernel        : 6.6.0

ipywidgets       : 7.6.5

jupyter_client   : 6.1.12

jupyter_core     : 4.9.1

jupyter_server   : 1.13.1

jupyterlab       : 3.2.5

nbclient         : 0.5.9

nbconvert        : not installed

nbformat         : 5.1.3

notebook         : 6.4.4

qtconsole        : 5.2.2

traitlets        : 5.1.1

It is like my jupyter doesn't recognize nbconvert 5.6.1 version.

I need jupyter 5.6.1 because my generate feedback is not working.

When I install any version of nbconverter 6.x.x it recognizes it.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: nbconvert 5.6.1 is 2 1/2 years old, which is a lifetime for jupyter. why not try to fix your application to use the current version? not sure what your "generate feedback" means but you might have better luck asking about how to correctly use the current version of jupyter rather than installing a super old version. Also please see the guide on [ask] and especially how to [format your code](/help/formatting). Thanks!